# compile error related to "in expansion of macro ‘CHKERRQ"’

Tags: petsc

I have this compiler error related to "in expansion of macro ‘CHKERRQ’" from PETSC whenever I call "CHKERRQ",  I am not sure what causes it, could anyone please give any advice?

Thanks for your help in advance,

Feng

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem in the end. The return type of my function is void. I need to set the return type of my function, which calls lots of PETSC routines, to PetscErrorCode.

Comment: You can use CHKERRABORT() instead in a void function,